# Parse XML into String type array in Windows Phone 8 App using C#

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, windows-phone-8, arrays

I have an XML file, which I like to parse and get the value in a string type array. I know there are XMLSerialization namespace and other things. But what I am trying to achieve is getting the value in a string array. It may be obtained using Foreach loop or for loop.

For example, here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<channel>
<title>Social Media</title>
<item>
<title>Facebook</title>
<link>http://www.facebook.com/</link>
</item>
<item>
<title>Twitter</title>
<link>http://www.twitter.com/</link>
</item>
<item>
<title>Google+</title>
<link>http://plus.google.com/</link>
</item>
</channel>
```

Now, I have two string type array as variable into a C# file.

For example:

```
public string[] WebsiteName;
public string[] Urls;
```

Now, I want to get all the values of WebsiteName into the WebsiteName array and website links into the Urls array.

Is there any way to do it? If yes, please show it to me. It will be very helpful.

Comment: use LINQ for that and make projection

Comment: Will you kindly give me a example of code how to use projection? I am not very skilled yet. So I don't know how to do it. @techloverr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to get website names and links using LINQ:

```
var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
<channel>
<title>Social Media</title>
<item>
<title>Facebook</title>
<link>http://www.facebook.com/</link>
</item>
<item>
<title>Twitter</title>
<link>http://www.twitter.com/</link>
</item>
<item>
<title>Google+</title>
<link>http://plus.google.com/</link>
</item>
</channel>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
WebsiteName = doc.Descendants("title").Select(o => o.Value).ToArray();
Urls = doc.Descendants("link").Select(o => o.Value).ToArray();
```

- `XDocument.Parse(xml)`: create XDocument from string. If you want the source is file instead of string then you can use `XDocument.Load("path_to_the_xml_file")`.
- `doc.Descendants("title")`: will get all tags named "title", then
- `.Select(o => o.Value)`: will get the string between the opening and closing tag, aka the value

Comment: I am parsing from a xml file in stead of string. So, I used XDocument.Load("FilePath"); But I am having an exception in here: A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.ni.dll. Can you please tell me the solution of it?

Comment: hmm.. that error message is not specific enough to know what is the actual problem. Have you tried to debug, to get more detailed error message? Maybe the file containing invalid xml format, missing closing tag or sth?

Comment: I have a xml file called SocialMedia.xml.

When I copy the whole code from there and write the code in my C# file the way you have describe above, it works perfectly.

var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
<channel>
<title>Social Media</title>
<item>
<title>Facebook</title>
<link>http://www.facebook.com/</link>
</item>
<item>
<title>Twitter</title>
<link>http://www.twitter.com/</link>
</item>
<item>
<title>Google+</title>
<link>http://plus.google.com/</link>
</item>
</channel>";

But I am trying to get the values directly from the XML file.

Comment: For example:

I have a folder named Social and inside that folder is the SocialMedia.xml. (The code is all the same)

So, what I am trying to do is just parse the values from there.

For example, I tried in my C# code:

var doc = XDocument.Load("/Social/SocialMedia.xml");
/* I also tried var doc = XDocument.Load("Social/SocialMedia.xml");*/
WebsiteName = doc.Descendants("title").Select(o => o.Value).ToArray();
Urls = doc.Descendants("link").Select(o => o.Value).ToArray();

But this is what giving me the exception.

Comment: In case of WP apps, you need to include the xml file to project, have you done that?

Comment: These are the 3 exceptions that I am having:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll

@har07

Comment: I have also added these 2 namespace:

using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Linq;

And yes, the xml file is added into the project. Does they need to be referenced anyhow?

Comment: I've just tried, the error you got is from the application couldn't find xml file in given path. Try to go with this: `XDocument.Load(@"Social\SocialMedia.xml")`

Comment: I have given you a lot of trouble I guess. The problem was in my XML file. Sorry for that. :) I tried with a different XML file and that worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. Many many thanks from the bottom of my heart. :)

Comment: How can I do the same where my xml looks like : <xsi:value encoding="utf-16">| amount: 152.467</xsi:value> ?

Comment: @user1386966 I've seen your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22676544/2998271) before your comment. Thought Igor's answer is clear enough, hence my upvote. Turns out it isn't, I added my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var WebsiteName = doc.Descendants("title").Select(o => o.Value).ToArray();

ListBox.ItemsSource = WebsiteName;
```

And you get content written in listbox.